# Show Dialog, on Fragment working

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, progressdialog

I have a Fragment and at its onStart(), I made a lot of BD querys, that are long for 15 seconds. I want to show a Progress Dialog, with a "loading circle". 
My app, has just one Activity, the Main. This, starts the first Fragment, and from this, I jump to other Fragment, and the same for the next. For to pass from one Fragment to other, I use the next static method.

```
public static startFragment(FragmentTransaction FT, Fragment newFragmentToOpen)
{
   FT.replace(R.id.Container, newFragmentToOpen);
   FT.addToBackStack(null);
   FT.commit();
}
```

I tried make a Thread in that method what starts the Progress Dialog, but it didn´t work. I tried to start the dialog on the OnCreate() method of the Fragment, and that didn´t work too.

What can I do?

Thank you.

(Edit)
I tried to start the Progress Dialog inside of the Fragment, at the onCreateView() and at onViewCreated(). It didn´t work, but if I debug step by step, I see that at the moment when the flow goes to the onStart() (where it is for 10 seconds usinig a DB), the ProgressDialog stops.

By this test, I understand, that the ProgressDialog is correctly showed, but when I go to onStart(), it disappear.

(Edit)

The problem is, that at the onStart() of the Fragment, I am working on the views, addking elements. I need, that while these elements are loading, a dialog be showed, because now, for the user it seems that the app is sttoped while it loads. I would need something like this:

```
public static startFragment(FragmentTransaction FT, Fragment newFragmentToOpen)
{
    startProgressDialog();

    FT.replace(R.id.container, newFragmentToOpen);
    FT.addToBackStack(null);
    FT.commit();

    stopProgressDialog();
}
```

But it doesn´t work, because the progress Dialog just begins when the view of the Fragment is fully loaded.

Comment: please add the code of what u tried earlier, will help understanding question well.

Comment: It is too much code. As I say at the post, my app is bassed on Fragments. I have a lot of fragments, that are called one to the next. I use for that, a static method (showed at the first post). At the Fragments, on the OnStart() I make a lot of DB sentences, then I need that while the 10 seconds that it is loading, something be showed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

1. To create STATIC vars.These will contain the info that I am going to use in the OnStart() of the Fragment.
2. Before to make the transition of the Fragment, start the Progress Dialog.
3. After of starting the Progress Dialog, start a THREAD.
4. (INTO THE THREAD) Load the info into the static vars.
5. (INTO THE THREAD) After load all the info, close the Progress Dialog.
6. (INTO THE THREAD) Call to the Fragment to load.
7. Finish of the Thread.
8. Into de Fragment, at OnStart(), take the info from the STATIC vars.

Answer (score 0):

You should try showing the dialog in `onCreateView()` since this is where the UI components are displayed in a `Fragment`

Comment: It doesn´t work. I have this: 

    private static ProgressDialog espera;

    @ Nullable
    @ Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        LayoutInflater inflador;

        inflador = inflater;
        espera = new ProgressDialog(inflador.getContext());
        espera.setMessage("Loading");
        espera.setIndeterminate(true);
        espera.show();

        return inflador.inflate(R.layout.layout_fragment_clasificaciones_wec,container, false);
    }

I tried too to call the "show" at onStart();

Comment: Did you try new ProgressDialog(getActivity()) instead of new ProgressDialog(inflador.getContext())

Comment: It doesn´t work too. I am trying to work at onViewCreated() method, but with no results.